# What does address(0) mean?

Tags: solidity, addresses, mapping

Referring to this link: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

looking at the last contract. (Line 130)

```
function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {
    return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
}
```

Why do we use `balances[address(0)]` here? Is that means we will get the sum of all values in the balances?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`balances` is a mapping of address to how many tokens that address owns.

`balances[address(0)]` then means how many tokens the address 0 (0x00000000...00) owns.

Although I don't like the practice, some ERC20 tokens consider tokens that are sent to address 0 to be "burned" and thus don't count them in the total. So `_totalSupply - balances[address(0)]` gives the total number of tokens minus those that have been "burned" by transferring them to address 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Who will actually send to address(0) then? By mistakes, error in contract or glitches in blockchain?

Comment: The expectation is that people send to `address(0)` on purpose to burn tokens.

Comment: And also due to human error, when no data is passed to the function, by default zero address is used.

Comment: @smarx why don't you like this practice? I'm implementing it on my token's contract as I will be burning tokens sometimes and want the total in circulation to show. Are there any drawbacks to it?

Comment: I don't like special cases. Why are tokens owned by address 0 not counted but tokens owned by address 1 are? I'd prefer an explicit `burn()` function.

Comment: Does address(0) have a private key?